# Is there any method or parameter to get the invalid/stop card information from stripe api I get only expiry month/year from stripe

Tags: java, android, api, stripe-payments

Is there any method or parameter from stripe where I get the information every time when I get card details of the customer to identify this card is valid/Stop or not because in my case user added his card and after that, he stops his credit card then after he his able to do the payment.

I already check user card expiry detail(month/year) that I get from stripe API.

```
ExternalAccountCollection externalAccountCollection = 
Customer.retrieve(user.getCustomer_id()).getSources().list(cardParams;

List<ExternalAccount> externalAccounts = new ArrayList<>(); 
externalAccounts.addAll(externalAccountCollection.getData());
Card card = (Card) externalAccounts.get(0);
```

I get below parameters from card object.

`addressCity, addressCountry, addressLine1, addressLine1Check;  addressLine2,  addressState,  addressZip, addressZipCheck, availablePayoutMethods brand country currency cvcCheck
defaultForCurrency dynamicLast4 Month Year fingerprint
funding last4 name recipient status tokenizationMethod`

Answer (score 0):

when you use stripe you have to enter card number, exp date, cvc in form then stripe check this card and return token , if you want to check card expiry use this :

```
 Card card = new Card("4242424242424242", 12, 2020, "123");  
 if (!card.validateCard())
     {// Do not continue token creation.
    }
 else
 {
  // generate token
 }
```